# Row size of a Grid in Extjs 3

Tags: extjs, grid, row

I would change the size of the rows of my grid.

Comment: From what size? To what size? Are you talking about height and/or width of cells? Do you mean entire row and/or column size? What code have you already tried? Help us help you.

Comment: I would change the size of the entire row. I used this code but it change all the grids and would change only 1 grid.                  .x-grid3-row {height: 20px;}
.x-grid3-row-table TD {line-height: 16px;}

Answer (score 1):

With CSS:

```
.x-grid3-row {height: 20px;}
.x-grid3-row-table TD {line-height: 16px;}
```

Comment: This works with all the grids but i would change the height of only 1 grid.

Comment: you can add some cls to your 1 grid, and modify this CSS with this cls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getRowClass.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Sample grid',
    cls: 'my_grid',
    store: 'storeName',   
    columns: [
       { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
       { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email' },
       { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex){
            return 'row_'+rowIndex;
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Now style like this

```
.my_grid .row_0{
    height: 50px;
};
.my_grid .row_1{
    height: 60px;
};
```